# ¿Como crear la relacion de dos tablas en laravel lumen?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo dos tablas unidas tal que así 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi  proyecto `Laravel` cual seria la relación que tendría que poner en el modelo

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Archivo extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
        'ruta',
    ];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las relaciones aquí está definidas [Uno a muchos *(hasMany)*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) y en forma inversa [belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) para desde el archivo poder obtener a que usuario le pertenece.

Modelo **User**

```
public function archivos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Archivo');
}
```

Modelo **Archivo**

```
public function usuario()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Si tiene problemas con `belongsTo` *(puede que no)* puede especificar las columna de su clave foránea de su modelo con respecto a `User`

```
public function usuario()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}
```

Y cuando desee obtener por ejemplo los archivos de un usuario sería

```
$usuario = User::find(1);
$archivos = $usuario->archivos;
dd($archivos);
```

Y si desea obtener el Usuario de un archivo

```
$archivo = Archivo::find(1);
dd($archivo->usuario);
```